# How to delimit the fields of an input file which has special characters?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am a newbie in shell scripting. I have a requirement to delimit the file fields of an input file having special characters and spaces with ";".

Input file:

```
----------------------------------
Server                    Port
----------------------------------
Local                      1001

-----------------------------------------
Name        Country        Count
-----------------------------------------
XXX          Bermuda        999
```

So my requirement is to get the output like,

Output :

```
Server;Port;Name;Country;Count
Local;1001;XXX;Bermuda;999
```

Please help me to fulfil the requirement.
I prefer any tool, be it awk, sed, etc. and I don't want the dash lines

Comment: Is that the total file?

Comment: Yes, it's the complete file

Comment: How much variation is there?  Could you have two words in the country name (Saudi Arabia)?  Could there be more than two groups of lines?  Could the data ever be a single field?  It's easy enough to write code that will handle that file; the question is — what other files should it also handle?

Comment: Thanks for your reply jonathan.. Yes there can be country name with space inbetween ex: south africa. We can consider like fields more than one space should be delimited with ";".. Ex 1001;Steve smith;Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started,

1. Remove lines that are blank or have `----` in them with `sed`. IF your files are all of the same layout as the example, that will result in header lines on odd lines and data lines on even.
2. Entab the file with the POSIX utility `unexpand` This terns runs of spaces into tabs but leaves single spaces alone. (this is not necessary if the file is already TSV.)
3. Use `awk` to now process the entabbed file into a header row and data row separated by `;`

Demo:

```
sed -E '/^--*$|^$/d' file | unexpand -a | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} 
                                                    NR%2 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                                                                gsub(/^[ ]+/,"",$i)
                                                                h=h ? h ";" $i : $i ";" }
                                                                next} 
                                                          {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                                                                gsub(/^[ ]+/,"",$i)
                                                                b=b ? b ";" $i : $i ";" }
                                                                }       
                                                    END{print h
                                                        print b}'
```

Prints:

```
Server;;;;Port;Name;Country;Count
Local;;;;1001;XXX;Bermuda;999
```

This will support data fields with spaces, such as 'Saudi Arabia'

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `sed` and `awk`

```
sed -E '/^-/d;/^$/d;s/[[:space:]]+/;/g' file | 
awk '{d[NR%2]=(d[NR%2]?d[NR%2]";":"")$0}END{print d[1]; print d[0]}'
```

or `awk` only

```
awk '/^-/ || !NF{next}{
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,";")
    d[i%2]=(d[i%2]?d[i%2]";":"")$0
    ++i
}END{print d[0]; print d[1]}' file
```

you get,

```
Server;Port;Name;Country;Count
Local;1001;XXX;Bermuda;999
```

**Edit: with input type `john smith` or `Saudi Arabia`**

```
----------------------------------
Server                    Port
----------------------------------
Local                      1001

-----------------------------------------
Name        Country        Count
-----------------------------------------
john smith          Saudi Arabia        999
```

you can use `[[:space:]][[:space:]]+` instead of `[[:space:]]+`

you get,

```
Server;Port;Name;Country;Count
Local;1001;john smith;Saudi Arabia;999
```

Comment: This is the best solution as long as there are no spaces in the names like 'Saudi Arabia'

Comment: @dawg only use `[[:space:]][[:space:]]+` instead of `[[:space:]]+`

Answer (score 0):

Awk only. It assumes that delimiter is two or more spaces, so that multipart names such as `Ber muda` could be possible:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
         FS="  +";            # delimiter is two or more spaces
         OFS=";"              # output delimiter
     } 
     /^-*$/ { next }          # dashed or empty records are discarded
     {
         $1=$1;               # rebuild records to change delimiters
         if(/^Server|^Name/)  # gather header
             h=h $0 OFS; 
         else                 # gather data
             d=d $0 OFS
     } 
     END {                    # print header and data record
         print h; 
         print d
     }' file
Server;Port;Name;Country;Count;
Local;1001;XXX;Ber muda;999;
```

Downside is trailing `OFS` but that one could be removed with a couple of `sub`s.